# How to query values of Accountid in results file of Bulk API?

Tags: apex, bulk-api, jobid

I am just finding out ways on how to retrieve the "Accountid" of results obtained from bulk CSV file.Will it be possible to retrieve using job id?If so Can you please explain on how to acquire it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's entirely possible to do this via REST. The details of how to do this are explained very clearly in the [Bulk API section of the Trailhead API module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/api_basics/api_basics_bulk).

Using Workbench you can query `/services/async/XX.0/job/jobID/batch` where XX.0 is the API number you're using for import via a GET call.

Once you have the results of the above, expand the folder for each batch and get the `Id` under batchinfo for each item. Use that `Id` and query again using GET in the following format for each Id:

```
/services/async/XX.0/job/jobID/batch/Id/result
```

Now you can expand each item to see the results and get the `accountId`.

You'll need a `sessionId` to do this as explained in the module which also includes instructions on how to get one.

**EDIT**

Via Apex:

Since it would be an `AsyncApexJob` and , I'd expect you'd need to lookup the  `batchprocessid` in the `ApexFlexQueue` to get the `AsyncApexJobId` (possibly the FlexQueueId although I wouldn't expect that to be the same as the above mentioned jobId). Once you had that, you should be able to construct a SOQL query using those `Ids` which would be very similar to what I outlined above.

Looking at the Apex Developer Guide for more on [Batch Apex and JobIds](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm). Here's some example code from that section of the Dev Guide:

```
AsyncApexJob aaj = [SELECT Id, Status, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, NumberOfErrors 
                FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ID =: batchprocessid ];
```

The Status to use would be 'Completed'.

Comment: Thanks @ crmprogdev, but I would like to know whether its  possible to query it in apex class?

Comment: @Pri Would have been helpful had you stated that in your question. Have edited to give you some guidance.